QGIS is not properly closing some PostgreSQL binary cursor, letting DB transactions with a state "idle in transaction"
In a QGIS 3.34.5-Prizren project having PostgreSQL/PostGIS layers, I can sometimes see such queries for different layers in the "Debugging/Development Tools" tab, under the "Query logger":
BEGIN READ ONLY;DECLARE qgis_5 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary("geom",'NDR'),"id","type"::text,"property"::text FROM "schema"."table" WHERE "geom" && st_makeenvelope(2731340.21,1279018.80,2731382.45,1279048.15,2056)
FETCH FORWARD 2000 FROM qgis_5

But they do not have corresponding CLOSE statements.
And QGIS itself finally becomes unresponsive, freezes with this white shade overlay all over the QGIS window (I have to force kill the application at this stage; it never recorvers).
On the PostGIS (16.2-3.4) database side, there are some transactions corresponding to the query above which hangs for ever, having a status: "idle in transaction" and modes such as "AccessShareLock" and "ExclusiveLock".
That's probably why QGIS also hangs, being unable to finish some action.
There is no particular user action triggering this state and this makes the issue hard to debug: it happens randomly, it can even happen just after opening the project. But it always appears at some point in time.
Is this a known bug today and what could I do to avoid id?
